# Offset 3D player to be on a point on a curve (has animations and axis aligned bounding box)

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have a 3D race with a few players, all of them follow a curve from A to B.

(I am going to talk about the curve from 0.0 (start) to 1.0 (end) (normalized) from now on).

I have a point on the spline that is set near the end of the curve (lets say 0.8), which is the finish line, I am trying to know if a player has passed the finish line, and I want to **offset** that player to be **exactly** on that point (the finish line).

This is a problem for me because:

1. The players have animations so the bounding box change scale overtime. (so I can't just place them on the point of the finish line)
2. The players might turn 180deg on the curve so the face is now the other way around *but* the bounding box doesn't have that information, so I couldn't find a way to place a point on the **front** of the player.

The data I have:

- The players 3D positions
- The players 1D position on the curve
- The 1D position of the finish line
- The bounding box of the players (axis aligned)

  - Contains the center point of the player.
  - Contains the extents of the bounding box (which is **half** the size of the bounding box)
- The curve data (at any point), tangents, bi-tangents, normals, positions

If I am missing any information let me know, I'll keep this post updated as I find new things.

EDIT: I can't seem to find the right title for the problem, if anyone has any suggestion that would be great!

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "passed the finish line"?  Your data doesn't seem to have motion information, but your question does include this.